# Date have no data and will show the date with Zero Data in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I have an output like this on my Crystal Reports:

```
Example: 
   Date(as group)| Hours | Counts
   ----------------------------------
   01-Feb-2018   |   20  |   5 
   03-Feb-2018   |   25  |   3 
   04-Feb-2018   |   22  |   3 
   05-Feb-2018   |   21  |   2 
   07-Feb-2018   |   28  |   1 
   10-Feb-2018   |   23  |   1
```

If you can see, there are days that missing because no data/empty, but I want the missing days to be shown and have a value of zero:

```
     Date        | Hours | Counts
   ----------------------------------
   01-Feb-2018   |   20  |   5 
   02-Feb-2018   |    0  |   0
   03-Feb-2018   |   25  |   3 
   04-Feb-2018   |   22  |   3 
   05-Feb-2018   |   21  |   2
   06-Feb-2018   |    0  |   0 
   07-Feb-2018   |   28  |   1 
   08-Feb-2018   |    0  |   0
   09-Feb-2018   |    0  |   0
   10-Feb-2018   |   23  |   1
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I think you will have to deal with that outside Crystal Reports. What is your datasource?

Comment: im using SQL database with procedure.